# How do I delete collection view cells along with this behaviour?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

[image]

I am using the following code. This code just removes the collection view cell by fading them and moving the rest below it upwards. I am not sure how I should be able to do this animation. Help is much appreciated.

```
func remove()
    {
        totalItems -= 1
        data.remove(at: itemIdValue)
        collectionView.deleteItems(at: [indexPathValue])
    }


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
   let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? InviteTasker1CellView
    cell.invitationSent()
    indexPathValue = indexPath
    itemIdValue = indexPath.item
    remove()
   }
```

Maybe it can be done better using Table view but I am not sure of a solution.

**Please help me with understanding how you would do it? Thanks a lot.**

Comment: The usual technique is to subclass the collection view layout and implement `finalLayoutAttributesForDisappearingItem`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

UICollectionView and UITableView create a default animation which is the one you want when you delete cells from them. 
Although, since you are using only one column, I'd suggest that you use a UITableView instead of a UICollectionView.
To remove a row from a tableview with the animation, do the following :

```
self.yourDataSourceArray.removeValue(at: self.indexPath.row)
self.tableView?.deleteRows(at: [self.indexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic)
```

If you still want to use a UICollectionView, here's how to do it :

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    self.yourDataSourceArray.remove(at: indexPath.row)
    collectionView.deleteItems(at: [indexPath])
}
```

Comment: @Sylvia, but this will not add the type of animation mentioned in the question. How would I do that animation here? Thanks.

Comment: If you use the function deleteItems(...) or deleteRows(...), the animation will be taken care of automatically by the UICollection or the UITableView. As you can see in the deleteRows(...), you also can specify a different UITableRowViewAnimation if the default one does not suit your need.

Comment: Thank you, I used table view for the same but with animation: .top (or .bottom would work too).