# How to delete collectionViewCell with animate?

Tags: swift, collectionview

i have a collectionView with 6 cells that i need to delete if i tap on the cell.
(It is going to be animated. The cell is shifted to the right to the end of the screen. And the cell below takes the position of the first cell) I guess it is stanart animate, is it?

So i have collectionViewDelegate

```
extension MainVC: UICollectionViewDelegate {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
       // collectionView.deleteItems(at: [indexPath])
       // collectionView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

so what methods do i need to put here?

Comment: Did you check the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52894616/how-do-i-delete-collection-view-cells-along-with-this-behaviour ?

Comment: It seems interesting, but it is standart animation that makes opacity like 0. I need to move me cell.

"The cell is shifted to the right to the end of the screen. And the cell below takes the position of the first cell)"

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to delete and animate the collectionview.

```
self.array.removeValue(at: self.indexPath.row)
self.collectionView.deleteItemsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], animationStyle: .automatic)
```